# Help me I cant do updates with these two errors :(

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

These are the two errors:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages

http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages

I need help removing them Please help i want to check for updates
Ubuntu 13.04

it still goes through but i want to get rid of them

Comment: It looks like those ppas are inactive, as the link in your question is dead with a 404error as well. See this question for help  [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

Remove them with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:upubuntu-com/office 
sudo apt-get update
```